# Is it not possible to access user snippets from command palette?

Tags: code-snippets

I have created a few user snippets in VS Code, brought up Command Palette and searched for them with no results.

I know that I can access these in the actual code editor inline by using the `prefix`.

Is there a way to see all matching snippets when searching in command palette like how it's possible in Sublime Text?